# Regex for URL path and query. (CodeScan warns of 'Polynomial regular expression')

Tags: regex

Writing a regex that'll validate that some inputs are known link formats which I use on my site, an example would be `/section/my-article-1?test=b`

The requirements are

- leading slash
- the path just contains alfanumerics, dashes and slashes
- queryparams are allowed

My regex is

```
/^((\/)[\dA-Za-z-]+)*(\/)?([&?=\dA-Za-z-])*$/;
```

This kinda works but it's not optimized.

Github CodeScan shows the warning **'Polynomial regular expression'**
https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/java/java-polynomial-redos/

I assume that's because the groups `[\dA-Za-z-]` and `[&?=\dA-Za-z-]` potentially could overlap and cause slowness. But I'm unsure of how to improve it while still allowing queryparams.

**How would I optimize the regex?**

Here's some testdata I've used

```
SHOULD MATCH
/
/section
/section/article-1
/section/article-1/
/section/article-1?x=y&hello=world

SHOULD NOT MATCH
section/article-1
/section/!$*
/x(1)
```

PS: my current regex does allow multiple slashes after eachother, which is undesirable so preventing that would also be a bonus.

Comment: `^(?:/[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*(?:/[&?=0-9A-Za-z-]*)?$` looks safe enough. Does it also complain of this pattern?

Comment: A bit faster variant: `^(?:/(?:[0-9A-Za-z-]+/)*[&?=0-9A-Za-z-]*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

See the [Recommendation](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/javascript/js-polynomial-redos/#recommendation):

> Modify the regular expression to remove the ambiguity, or ensure that the strings matched with the regular expression are short enough that the time-complexity does not matter.

Change the pattern to such a *regex that does not allow each subsequent part to match at the same location*:

```
^(?:/(?:[0-9A-Za-z-]+/)*[&?=0-9A-Za-z-]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sHyF1L/3).

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:/(?:[0-9A-Za-z-]+/)*[&?=0-9A-Za-z-]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `/` - a slash
  - `(?:[0-9A-Za-z-]+/)*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more alphanumeric or hyphen chars and then a `/` char
  - `[&?=0-9A-Za-z-]*` - zero or more alphanumeric, hyphen, `=`, `?` or `&` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Just to show why it is efficent:

- `^` - matches start of string
- `(?:/(?:[0-9A-Za-z-]+/)*[&?=0-9A-Za-z-]*)?` - either starts matching with `/` that is at the start of string, or matches an empty string

  - `(?:[0-9A-Za-z-]+/)*` - requires alphanumeric/hyphen to appear after a `/` (`[0-9A-Za-z-]` does not match `/`), and ends matching with a `/` if matched
  - `[&?=0-9A-Za-z-]*` only matches the chars in the class if preceded with a `/` char that is missing from the character class (i.e. no overlapping here, either)
- `$` - matches end of string.

Now, if the warning is still there, you can safely ignore it.